# How do I push multiple events to google analytics on page load?

Tags: google-analytics, google-datalayer

I'm attempting to do two pushes to the analytics datalayer when my ecommerce receipt page loads.

My issue is that I can only ever pick up one of the two events.

I'm outputting this on the receipt page:

```
<script>
    function trackEcommerce() {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'checkout',
            'ecommerce': {
                'checkout': {
                    'actionField': { 'step': 2 }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    dataLayer.push({
        'event' : 'purchaseEvent',
        'ecommerce': {
            'purchase': {
                'actionField': {
                    'id': '@orderId',                         
                    'affiliation': 'Eldorado',
                    'revenue': '@OrderTotal.ToString("F", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))',                     
                    'tax':'@VatTotal.ToString("F", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))',
                    'shipping': '@ShippingFee.ToString("F", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))'
                    },
                'products': [
                    @foreach (var item in GetLoop("OrderLines"))
                    {
                        string productName = item.GetString("Ecom:Product.Name").Replace("\"", "").Trim();
                        string productNumber = item.GetString("Ecom:Product.Number");
                        double orderLineUnitPrice = item.GetDouble("Ecom:Order:OrderLine.UnitPrice.PriceWithoutVAT.Value");
                        int orderLineQuantity = item.GetInteger("Ecom:Order:OrderLine.Quantity");
                        string brand = item.GetString("Ecom:Product:Field.Brands.Value");
                        var DwProduct = ProductService.GetProductById(item.GetString("Ecom:Order:OrderLine.ProductID"), item.GetString("Ecom:Order:OrderLine.ProductVariantID"), item.GetString("Ecom:Product.LanguageID"));
                        string category = DwProduct.DefaultGroup == null ? "" : DwProduct.DefaultGroup.Name;                        
                        <text>{
                            'name': '@productName',
                            'id': '@productNumber',
                            'price': '@orderLineUnitPrice.ToString("F", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))',
                            'brand': '@brand',
                            'category': '@category',
                            'quantity': @orderLineQuantity
                        },</text>
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        'eventCallback': trackEcommerce()
    });
</script>
```

I've tried formatting this code in a variety of different ways. I've had the callback function call the second dataLayer push directly like:

```
'eventCallback': function () {
            dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'checkout',
                'ecommerce': {

                }
            });
        }
```

I've also attempted just outputting the two dataLayer pushes in succession with no eventCallback or other relation between the two pushes.

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious thing is that you're using a function call `trackEcommerce()` instead of referencing a function like `'eventCallback': trackEcommerce`

However, just using two plain consequent pushes should work fine and would be easier to debug.

```
dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'checkout', ... });
// ... 
dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'purchaseEvent', ... })
```